# Only 2GB of Device Memory is shown on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, internal-storage

I have Samsung Galaxy S2 GT-I9100. As it has 16GB internal memory but it only shows that it has 1.97GB of device memory. I am not talking about the memory that is free after using some of the space. This is the max memory that it is showing.
I have tried resetting to factory settings and erasing everything. Also, I cleared cache and dump logs. Nothing have helped me yet.
When I connect it to my laptop, it shows that phone has 8.56GB used out of 11.4GB. But that is USB storage, isn't it?
Under settings > storage > device memory [Total space = 1.97 GB].
The problem arises when I install few of the applications and it starts showing that you are running out of storage.
I don't understand what it is showing only that much space.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are having issues with memory is because even though the phone has 16g internal memory only 1g. Is available to the user the rest is being used by the os and preloaded apps. If you go to settings and then phone storage it will show you the available internal memory.

Comment: Yes I have checked all that and I understood that it was the issue. What I wanted to know is how could I increase the device memory size and this link has helped me.
http://techotv.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-internal-storage-apps-space-tutorial/

Comment: Ok Please answer your question here so that if any body else have same problem they then know how can they achieve it.

Comment: @talzal Your question is not clear about you looking to re-partition internal space.  You may want to update your question.